# Do python files need to be on the same drive as the plugin Python-mode for its functionality to work

Tags: python, vim, python-mode

I'm using the plugin `python-mode` for `gVim` on a windows machine.

I have the following `python-mode` specific settings in my `vimrc` file:

```
"------------------------------------------------------------
" settings for Python-mode
" "-----------------------------------------------------------
map <Leader>g :call RopeGotoDefinition()<CR>
let ropevim_enable_shortcuts = 1
let g:pymode_rope_goto_def_newwin = "vnew"
let g:pymode_rope_extended_complete = 1
let g:pymode_breakpoint = 0
let g:pymode_syntax = 1
let g:pymode_syntax_builtin_objs = 0
let g:pymode_syntax_builtin_funcs = 0
map <Leader>b Oimport ipdb; ipdb.set_trace() # BREAKPOINT<C-c>

"Better navigating through omnicomplete option list
set completeopt=longest,menuone
function! OmniPopup(action)
    if pumvisible()
        if a:action == 'j'
            return "\<C-N>"
        elseif a:action == 'k'
            return "\<C-P>"
        endif
    endif
        return a:action
endfunction

inoremap <silent><C-j> <C-R>=OmniPopup('j')<CR>
inoremap <silent><C-k> <C-R>=OmniPopup('k')<CR>
```

These were suggested in [**this tutorial**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhqsjUUHj6g).

`vimrc` is on my `M:` drive.

Now if I open vim (set to open in the `M:` drive) and then open a python file on say the `P:` drive and then try to save that file I get the following error message:

[image]

If I move the file `pi.py` to the M: drive then everything is happy but surely to use files in `vim` it shouldn't be a condition that the file being edited is on the same drive as vim?

Can I change my settings for `Python-mode` to function on files from other drives?

---

**EDIT**
Python-mode has the following setting which looks promising:

> " Additional python paths
>   let g:pymode_paths = []

So in `vimrc` I've added

let g:pymode_paths = ['P:\Comp Apps\Python\']

But still if I open a .py file from that location i get the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I execute `:lcd %:p:h` then the python-mode plugin seems to be working. I can also use `set autochdir` in my `vimrc`: not sure if there are any disadvantages to using this setting.